# How to securely validate a REST client has legitimate access

Tags: android, ios, security, rest, single-page-application

Many companies that offer REST APIs permit access based on an API key. Developers embed those API keys in their iOS, Android or JavaScript SPA web apps.

Those keys are easily extracted, either by viewing the page source of a web app, or by disassembling the source code of an IPA, etc when you have root access to the device.

Whilst I am aware that iOS has the keychain in which such data can be secured (and I assume Android has something similar), it doesn't solve the JavaScript SPA client.

Whilst OAuth/OAuth2 and authentication token issuance can help to validate the user that logs in, it doesn't validate the legitimacy of the client application.

How can I go about guaranteeing the validity of the client application?

Comment: Have you read Oauth 2.0 specification? There is an entire section on client authentication...

Comment: on iOS storing the API key in code is perfectly safe (as long as only you have access it to it of course) since it's not possible to any "disassembling" here...

Comment: @user1431072 do you have a link? Google isn't helping me :( when I say "client" I mean "application" rather than "user".

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749 is where the specification is found -- and yes, I was also referring to an "application" when talking about the client

Comment: @user1431072 the problem still remains that I can't trust the JavaScript client to keep their API Key safe. I'm assuming that there is no flow, OAuth2 or otherwise that can prove that Client App A is Client App A and not Malious App B.

Comment: @Junto You are right, you can't trust what is being sent to the server. That's why you need to implement any security meaures possible on the authorization server to reduce the risk of intruders. What im saying is that the Oauth 2.0 specification gives you options for that kind of risk reduction.